# aws rds describe-db-snapshots --query

Tags: aws-cli

i wanted to customize output of **aws rds describe-db-snapshots** command to display only the identifier and sort it according to creation time!
 This is the output i am currently getting i would like to simplify that

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                                                                                                                                                                                 DescribeDBSnapshots                                                                                                                                                                                 |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
||                                                                                                                                                                                    DBSnapshots                                                                                                                                                                                    ||
|+------------------+-------------------+-----------------------+------------------------------------------------+------------+-------------+----------------+---------------------------+-------+-------------------------+-----------------+------------------+------------------+-------+---------------------------+---------------+------------+---------------+----------------+|
|| AllocatedStorage | AvailabilityZone  | DBInstanceIdentifier  |             DBSnapshotIdentifier               | Encrypted  |   Engine    | EngineVersion  |    InstanceCreateTime     | Iops  |      LicenseModel       | MasterUsername  | OptionGroupName  | PercentProgress  | Port  |    SnapshotCreateTime     | SnapshotType  |  Status    |  StorageType  |     VpcId      ||
|+------------------+-------------------+-----------------------+------------------------------------------------+------------+-------------+----------------+---------------------------+-------+-------------------------+-----------------+------------------+------------------+-------+---------------------------+---------------+------------+---------------+----------------+|
```

Answer (score -2):

```
aws rds describe-db-instances  --query 'DBInstances[*].[DBInstanceIdentifier,InstanceCreateTime]'
```

Comment: this command does not sort according to creation time as requested in this question.